# inserting into new added columns in an existing table

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I have a table 'user' already in db with fields

```
create Table user (
id INT(6) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
username varchar(20) NOT NULL,
password varchar(20) NOT NULL,
profilename varchar(20) NOT NULL,
email varchar(40) NOT NULL,
socialemail varchar(40) NOT NULL)engine=InnoDB;
```

The stated columns also contain values

I altered the table and added some more columns

```
ALTER TABLE user
ADD COLUMN enabled varchar(1),
ADD COLUMN accountnonexpired varchar(1),
ADD COLUMN credentialsnonexpired varchar(1),
ADD COLUMN accountnonlocked varchar(1);
```

Now when I am inserting values into new columns with the below command in MYSQL.

```
insert into user
(id,enabled,accountnonexpired,credentialsnonexpired,accountnonlocked) values ('1','Y','Y','Y','Y'),('2','Y','Y','Y','Y');
```

I am getting an error

```
Error Code: 1364. Field 'username' doesn't have a default value
```

Can anyone tell me why?
What should be the correct way to insert values in new columns?

[image]

Comment: The only thing wrong here is your idea that you need to `INSERT` into "new columns".  As far as the database is concerned, the columns exist.  You need to `UPDATE` the records with values for the EXISTING columns.  Make sense?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An `INSERT` is creating NEW records.  You have a username field that is marked as `NOT NULL`  But in your sql you are not including username and other `NOT NULL` fields in your statement.

Your insert would need to include all the `NOT NULL` fields.

```
insert into user(id,username,password,profilename,email,socialemail,enabled,accountnonexpired,credentialsnonexpired,accountnonlocked) 
values ('1',<username>,<password>,<profilename>,<email>,<socialemail>'Y','Y','Y','Y'),('2',<username>,<password>,<profilename>,<email>,<socialemail>'Y','Y','Y','Y');
```

I suspect you actually want to UPDATE here instead of insert.

An update would look like this:

```
UPDATE user set enabled = 'Y', accountnonexpired='Y', credentialsnonexpired='Y', accountnonlocked='Y'
FROM user
WHERE id = 1
```

Comment: you don't need a FROM clause in an UPDATE statement, do you?

Answer (score 4):

`INSERT` adds new rows to your table, and those rows would have to have a non-null username for the `INSERT` to succeed It's not 100% clear but I think you are saying that you want to set the values of these new columns *for all your existing rows*. To do that you need `UPDATE` not `INSERT`:

```
UPDATE user SET id='1', enabled = 'Y', accountnonexpired = 'Y' WHERE 1
```

I omitted a few of your columns for brevity but you get the idea. You may also want to alter the table to make these values the `DEFAULT` for new rows inserted in the future.

Answer (score 3):

Your table has NOT NULL set for the [username], [password], [profilename], [email] and  [socialemail] fields. You will need to provide values while NOT NULL has been set and there is no default value.

Unless your intention is to insert data into pre-existing columns, then use the Update statement.

```
 update user
    set enabled = 'Y', accountnonexpired='Y', credentialsnonexpired='Y', accountnonlocked='Y'
    from user
    where id = 1
```

Answer (score 0):

Give value for 'username' field. it has no default value and default is not null as per your table definition. This will work

Comment: I have edited my question the existing field already contain values.

Answer (score 0):

In your insert procedure, there is no value assigned for username field, Since `username varchar(20) is NOT NULLable`, you need to set a default value for that col or alter the col property to accept null values.